# How to repair applications using 'msiexec /f appname'

Tags: windows-installer

I want to execute the 'msiexec' command to repair an installed application.
I.e. in the application, I will add a string value into a specified key in the registry.
After old version is installed, I check the registry table, it's ok. The string value is "3.0.0.2". Then I use another installer which is the same as the previous one and it will change the string value into "3.0.0.6" in the registry.

After execution, the value doesn't change!
The problem confused me for several days.
Here is my msiexec command line to repair the application:

```
msiexec ApplicationName="Mobile" /fvomusa "asset.msi" /L log.txt
```

How can I execute the msiexec correctly to modify the registry value? I tried several '/f' args composition, such as '/fvmusa', '/f', '/fva' and so on, but to no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the possible command lines:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367575(v=vs.85).aspx

The installer properties list should be last, not before "/fvomusa". Also, try using a [public property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (no lowercase letters in its name) instead of a private one.

Comment: @JefferyYou to be quite useful you should have posted the command you used ;-)